# How to build 64bit Qt 5.3 for Windows 7 x64? Is there any differences between builds with MinGW-w64 and MSVS?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, mingw-w64

Maybe this question is very simple and was asked a lot of times, but, despite that I googled a lot, I can't find step-by-step instructions for building Qt. All of them either for Qt4 or contains some bugs. I need 64bit version of Qt for Windows 7. How it can be done?

Comment: Yes, tried to do twice. But during last step there is a message: "Can't find icuin.dll" or smth like that.

Comment: Typically, yes there are differences. I advise you to use same compiler across your project and check what Qt devs prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that qt [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-building.html) on building from source and [requirements](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-requirements.html) look like step-by-step instruction on how to build Qt5. If you follow the steps thoroughly, you'll be able to do this.

In particular your issue "Can't find icuin.dll" tells that you didn't install [icu](http://site.icu-project.org/download). You have an option to either install it, or specify option "-no-icu" when running configuration script.

If you build MSVS version, you should build Qt form MSVS x64 console, that you can find in Start menu->programs->MSVS folder. In this case you will not have to set some environment variables like QMAKESPEC, etc

Comment: How to build without running from console, i.e. from automated build script? What do one set QMAKESPEC to in that case?